# Angular CLI - Error while creating new app

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line-interface

Installed angular CLI and then tried to create a new Angular4 app through it.

I ran the following commands:

Installing CLI: ***npm install -g @angular/cli***

Creating a new project using CLI: ***ng new angu4-app***

**But i got the following error**

> node -v : v6.11.2
>
> npm -v : 5.3.0
>
> @angular/cli: 1.3.2
>
> os: win32 x64

```
    D:\Angular4>ng new angu4-app
installing ng
  create .editorconfig
  create README.md
  create src\app\app.component.css
  create src\app\app.component.html
  create src\app\app.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\app.component.ts
  create src\app\app.module.ts
  create src\assets\.gitkeep
  create src\environments\environment.prod.ts
  create src\environments\environment.ts
  create src\favicon.ico
  create src\index.html
  create src\main.ts
  create src\polyfills.ts
  create src\styles.css
  create src\test.ts
  create src\tsconfig.app.json
  create src\tsconfig.spec.json
  create src\typings.d.ts
  create .angular-cli.json
  create e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts
  create e2e\app.po.ts
  create e2e\tsconfig.e2e.json
  create .gitignore
  create karma.conf.js
  create package.json
  create protractor.conf.js
  create tsconfig.json
  create tslint.json
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:65316
npm ERR! 2.4.10","description":"Angular - the core framework","main":"bundles/
npm ERR!                                                                      ^

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vkaranat\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-28T14_26_48_240Z-debug.log

Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

**Below are the log details, which shows some error, which i am not able to figure out**
Has any one come across a similar issue.

```
2012 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at 1:65316
2012 verbose stack 2.4.10","description":"Angular - the core framework","main":"bundles/
2012 verbose stack                                                                      ^
2012 verbose stack     at SyntaxError (native)
2012 verbose stack     at Object.parseJSON (C:\Users\vkaranat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-helpfulerror\node_modules\jju\lib\parse.js:745:13)
2012 verbose stack     at parse (C:\Users\vkaranat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-helpfulerror\index.js:10:13)
2012 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Users\vkaranat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
2012 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
2013 verbose cwd D:\Vipin-Dump\__PlayGround\__Angular4\angu4-app
2014 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
2015 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\vkaranat\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--quiet" "install"
2016 verbose node v6.11.2
2017 verbose npm  v5.3.0
2018 error Unexpected end of input at 1:65316
2018 error 2.4.10","description":"Angular - the core framework","main":"bundles/
2018 error                                                                      ^
2019 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire: Have added the log details in my post and have also added the commands that i ran.

Comment: I'd just delete the global npm node_modules folder and reinstall.  Much easier (and probably faster) than figuring out some oddball versioning issue.

Comment: @Michael: tried that..deleted the npm_modules folder and reinstalled it... But i still get the same error... :(

Comment: Try cleaning your cache with `npm cache clean --force` then try again.  Based on the results I'm seeing, it looks like this occurs when some module isn't installed correctly. (see [here](https://github.com/zkat/pacote/issues/112))